# How to consume messages from JMS Topic in Java

Tags: java, jms, jms-topic

Yes, I have googled but it's very confusing to me. I want to continuously receive messages from a Topic (it's an oracle AQ topic) similar to the way that I use the MessageListener interface onMessage method for Queues. I can't seem to find a clear answer

With Queues - it's simple. Create an MDB publisher/producer class to send messages, and a Consumer class that implements MessageListener to receive messages. With Topics - there seems to be a different strategy when it comes to receiving.

I have tried examples that implement the MessageConsumer interface as well as MessageListener interface but nothing is really clear cut and nothing works for me. I have tried the subscriber.receive() method using MessageConsumer to create a durable subscriber on the topic session - not only does it not work but it only happens when you call the receive method, but I want something that will consume messages as and when they come.

Comment: Please share some code if you expect anyone to help you.

Comment: Both `MessageListener` and `MessageConsumer` should work. With JMS topics it's important to understand that you must create the subscription *before* messages are sent. Any message sent to the topic before the subscription is created will not be dispatched to that subscription's consumer. Also, ensure you invoke `start()` on the `Connection`.

Comment: Thanks @JustinBertram that helps a lot - didn't realise start() was important and I was trying to consume messages sent prior to the subscription

Comment: Is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

Both `MessageListener` and `MessageConsumer` *should* work. With JMS topics it's important to understand that you must create the subscription *before* messages are sent. Any message sent to the topic before the subscription is created will not be dispatched to that subscription's consumer. Also, ensure you invoke [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#start--) on the `Connection`.